# Unable to execute JDBC statement in sqldf in R

Tags: r, jdbc, sqldf

I am using sqlf in R to merge (join) two data sets. However, I get an error message:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(s, "Unable to execute JDBC statement ", statement) :
```

Here is an example:

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:6), Product = c(rep("Toaster", 3), rep("Radio", 3)))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(2, 4, 6), State = c(rep("Alabama", 2), rep("Ohio", 1)))
library(sqldf)
library(tcltk)
df3 <- sqldf("SELECT CustomerId, Product, State 
              FROM df1
              JOIN df2 USING(CustomerID)")
```

After running, I get the following error message:

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(s, "Unable to execute JDBC statement ", statement) : 
  Unable to execute JDBC statement SELECT CustomerId, Product, State 
              FROM df1
              JOIN df2 USING(CustomerID) (Ambiguous column name "CustomerId"; SQL statement:
SELECT CustomerId, Product, State 
              FROM df1
              JOIN df2 USING(CustomerID) [90059-175])
```

Here is the output after sessionInfo():

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      tcltk     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] sqldf_0.4-10    RSQLite_1.0.0   gsubfn_0.6-6    proto_0.3-10    Hmisc_3.16-0    ggplot2_1.0.1   Formula_1.2-1   survival_2.38-1 lattice_0.20-31 RH2_0.2.3       RJDBC_0.2-5     rJava_0.9-6    
[13] DBI_0.3.1       chron_2.3-45   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.11.6         cluster_2.0.1       magrittr_1.5        splines_3.2.0       MASS_7.3-40         munsell_0.4.2       colorspace_1.2-6    stringr_1.0.0       plyr_1.8.2         
[10] tools_3.2.0         nnet_7.3-9          gtable_0.1.2        latticeExtra_0.6-26 digest_0.6.8        gridExtra_0.9.1     RColorBrewer_1.1-2  reshape2_1.4.1      acepack_1.3-3.3    
[19] rpart_4.1-9         stringi_0.4-1       scales_0.2.4        foreign_0.8-63
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You presumably loaded the RH2 R package prior to running the code in the question so sqldf is using the H2 database rather than SQLite.

1. If you intended to use H2 then note that it does not support the `USING` keyword.  See http://www.h2database.com for H2 syntax.
2. If you did not intend to use H2 then (i) do not load it or else (ii) if you need it loaded then specify the sqlite database explicitly via `drv = "SQLite"` as one of the arguments to `sqldf` or else (iii) specify the appropriate global option: `options(sqldf.driver = "SQLite")` .

Also note that the `library(tcltk)` line is not needed.

Comment: Thank you G. Grothendieck. I detached the RH2 and tcltk packages and the program runs perfectly.

Comment: When you load sqldf it will automatically load tcltk. Do not detach it.

Comment: Thank you  G. Grothendieck.

Answer (score 0):

The error message *Ambiguous column name "CustomerId"* means that the database server has two or more tables containing the `CustomerId` column, and it doesn't know which to use to satisfy the `select`-clause. You need to explicitly specify the table to use:

```sql
SELECT df1.CustomerId, Product, State 
FROM df1
JOIN df2 USING(CustomerID)
```

Although it isn't necessary for columns that only occur in one table, it is better to do this for every column.